# What is the mathematical formulation of the probit function in SAS?

Tags: statistics, python, cumulative-distribution-functions

Can you please share the math for probit function available in sas.
I am trying to replicate it in Python.
SAS:

```
data one;
x=probit(0.008);
put x=;                                          
run;
```

Output:

```
x
-2.408915546
```

I tried below in python:
Values do not match

```
def normpdf(x, mean, sd):
   var = float(sd)**2
   denom = (2*math.pi*var)**.5
   num = math.exp(-(float(x)-float(mean))**2/(2*var))
   return num/denom
normpdf(0.008,0,1) 
0.3989295144527161
```

Please share the correct math for probit function

Comment: The probit function is the **inverse** of the normal CDF (CDF is the "integral" of the function that you try to calculate with the Python code). That means that
$$
\Phi^{-1}(0.008) \approx -2.4089
$$
your Python code calculates something else entirely, the density function. See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit

Comment: If you want to calculate this inverse normal CDF in Python, there's for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626994/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-the-normal-cumulative-distribution-function-in-p

Comment: Thank you for this...I am working on cdsw and due to not having the right admin rights and versions of scipy..its getting really complex to use just norm.ppf method... I am looking for a formula such as (1 + math.erf((x - mu) / (sigma * math.sqrt(2)))) / 2.....Can u help me with this....I have already tried using inverse function ..the values didnt match

Comment: Try `print(norm.ppf(0.008))` to get `-2.408915545815461` in Python